# the time the task is in progress

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

Let's suppose we are talking about managing a project, tracking progress of tasks:

> This chart is good, it shows which tasks are in progress and which ones are not started yet, but I also need to know **the time a task is in progress** by now.

Is the selected phrase grammatical, does it sound OK?

Comment: You've got a comma splice. Make the first comma a colon or a period. "Have not started" sounds better to me than "are not started yet," but that could be just personal preference. The present tense *is* conflicts with "by now." You need to know **the time a task has been in progress**.

Comment: Thank you very much!